# When using unicode-math, how do I get the original calligraphic alphabet back?

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, unicode-math

I am happy with the great majority of what `unicode-math` does. But at times I find that I prefer a symbol the way it was before. With `\varnothing` and `\complement`, for example. In those cases I was able to save them under a different name before loading `unicode-math`, but this doesn't always work.

Right now I'm trying to access the `\mathcal` alphabet from plain LaTeX. How might I accomplish this?

---

**Additional Question**

I've been looking through `unicode-math`, trying to figure out where exactly the original `\mathcal` alphabet gets discarded, but I eventually gave up.

It would be interesting if someone could explain:

- how/where the original `\mathcal` font is defined anyway, and
- what kind of 'switch' is thrown by `unicode-math` that makes it unavailable.

Comment: You can't, unless you are using CM Math (then it will be default) See also this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120065/xetex-what-happened-to-mathcal-and-mathscr

Comment: @HenriMenke Hm... But the comments there imply that you cannot use Computer Modern *at all* if you use `unicode-math`. So what do you mean by "unless"? --- Anyway, the notion that there's no way to do it is so silly I reject it. Even if I cannot just load it as a font, I could patch `unicode-math` to leave `\mathcal` alone or, as a last resort, I could typeset the alphabet in a box before loading `unicode-math` and then use the box. --- But I have to believe there are more elegant solutions than that.

Comment: Let me cite the following comment from the [linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120065/xetex-what-happened-to-mathcal-and-mathscr): »You can't use Computer Modern with `unicode-math`, the last example you get it from Latin Modern Math which is the closest you can get. – [Khaled Hosny](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729/khaled-hosny)« Please note, that Khaled Hosny is one of the original developers of `unicode-math`. Saving the alphabet to a box might indeed be possible, but will for sure bring several downsides.

Comment: I read those comments. And I have no doubt Khaled is right in that there is no standard option through the `unicode-math` interface by which the original font can be retrieved (perhaps there should be). But I would even be happy with a patch or 'hack' – one which is more elegant than using boxes. --- Indeed, storing those characters in boxes has downsides. I mention some in my answer below. --- Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @mhelvens The problem is that the entire math font mechanism is altered to deal with Unicode math fonts. For 'traditional' TeX, you simply change the family (`\mathcal` boils down to `\fam2`, at least 'out of the box'). That simply doesn't work once you switch to the Unicode mechanism, which doesn't use families at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just override the declarations with the original one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{DFIP}_{\mathcal{DFIP}_{\mathcal{DFIP}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output of `pdffonts`, showing that `cmsy` is used.

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
GQWLIO+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
NCPDNV+CMSY7                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
BZNGBB+CMSY5                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
MMERCJ+LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H  CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
```

Comment: And I guess this is the *actual* answer. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @mhelvens Sorry for being late; but maybe this wouldn't have worked at the time.

Comment: That's fine. I found a different solution at the time. And right now it's best to keep the Q&A's current.

Answer (score 3):

Very late answer, but you could also locally set the mathcodes of the letters to the ones plain TeX defines.  Then you load the Computer Modern Calligraphic fonts and redefine `\mathcal` to locally switch to this family and use the “legacy” mathcodes.

This solution is superior to the other answer, because you obtain proper scaling of the calligraphic letters in sub/superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newtoks\legacymathcodes\legacymathcodes={
\mathcode`A="7141 \mathcode`B="7142 \mathcode`C="7143
\mathcode`D="7144 \mathcode`E="7145 \mathcode`F="7146
\mathcode`G="7147 \mathcode`H="7148 \mathcode`I="7149
\mathcode`J="714A \mathcode`K="714B \mathcode`L="714C
\mathcode`M="714D \mathcode`N="714E \mathcode`O="714F
\mathcode`P="7150 \mathcode`Q="7151 \mathcode`R="7152
\mathcode`S="7153 \mathcode`T="7154 \mathcode`U="7155
\mathcode`V="7156 \mathcode`W="7157 \mathcode`X="7158
\mathcode`Y="7159 \mathcode`Z="715A
}

\font\tensy=cmsy10
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\newfam\cmcalfam
\textfont\cmcalfam=\tensy
\scriptfont\cmcalfam=\sevensy
\scriptscriptfont\cmcalfam=\fivesy
\protected\def\mathcal#1{{\fam\cmcalfam
    \the\legacymathcodes #1}}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{DFIP}_{\mathcal{DFIP}_{\mathcal{DFIP}}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

If you don't want to type all the mathcodes, e.g. in case you want to extend it to lowercase as well (which CM doesn't have), you could also set the mathcodes in a loop.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\font\tensy=cmsy10
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\newfam\cmcalfam
\textfont\cmcalfam=\tensy
\scriptfont\cmcalfam=\sevensy
\scriptscriptfont\cmcalfam=\fivesy
\protected\def\mathcal#1{%
  \begingroup
    \fam\cmcalfam
    \count0=`A
    \loop\ifnum\count0<\numexpr`Z+1\relax
      \mathcode\count0=\the\numexpr"7141 - `A + \count0\relax
      \advance\count0 by 1
    \repeat
    #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{DFIP}_{\mathcal{DFIP}_{\mathcal{DFIP}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep! That's definitely better. Accepted.

Comment: @mhelvens I improved my answer.  Especially note, that I have changed `\def\mathcal` to `\protected\def\mathcal`, which is more appropriate since assignments happen inside `\mathcal`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just share the solution I'm using at the moment. It's far from ideal, but it's fine if you only need a few letters of the calligraphic alphabet. For example, I need only D, F, I and P throughout my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\preserveCal[2]{
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname box@\string#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\savebox\csname box@\string#1\endcsname{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#2}}}
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter
        {\expandafter\usebox\csname box@\string#1\endcsname}
}
\preserveCal{\calD}{D}
\preserveCal{\calF}{F}
\preserveCal{\calI}{I}
\preserveCal{\calP}{P}
\makeatother

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \noindent$\mathcal{DFIP}$\par
    \noindent$\calD\calF\calI\calP$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a generally applicable 'last resort' way to preserve symbols that are destroyed by a package. The problem is that these don't scale with the font. Also, each symbol takes up a whole box register, and I believe there are only 256 box registers available.

Comment: I generally don't like to accept my own answers on SE, especially not this one. But since it is the only answer I've found that actually works, I will. If someone else shares a more elegant answer in the future, I'll happily surrender the green tick.