# I can't put accent on `\mathcal` after changing the font of `\mathcal`

Tags: unicode-math, accents, mathcal

When I use `unicode-math`, I found that there is no default performance of `\mathcal` in the 6 fonts given in `texdoc unimath-symbols`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $ \mathcal{DBFT} $
\end{document}
```

The code above will output

[image]

I found that `unicode-math` gives same performance of `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    $ \mathcal{DBFT}, \mathscr{DBFT} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

I found a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305501/180617) on TeX.SE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
$ \mathcal{DBFT}, \mathscr{DBFT} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

However that leads to a new problem. I can't put `\tilde` accent on `\mathcal` characters:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
$ \tilde{\mathcal{B}} $

% $ \hat{\mathcal{B}} $
\end{document}
```

After compiling with XeLaTeX, it gave an error:

```
! Internal error: bad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
```

Now I can use `\tilde{\text{$ \mathcal{B} $}}` to solve the problem, but this solution seems weird.

My requests:

1. I want to use the default `\mathcal` style of Computer Modern when I use `unicode-math` package (the first figure in this Question);
2. I want to use `\tilde{\mathcal{B}}` straight to put accent on `\mathcal{B}`.

Here is the same issue on GitHub (https://github.com/CTeX-org/forum/issues/179)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found a solution for legacy fonts that isn’t compatible with `unicode-math`.

Since Unicode maps `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` to the same characters, you can only set them to different alphabets if you load a new font with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  For example, this uses New Computer Modern Book for everything but `\mathscr` and `\mathbfscr`, which it takes from a stylistic set of STIX Two Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{NewComputerModernBook}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={scr,bfscr},
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  StylisticSet=1 ]

\begin{document}
\[ \tilde{\mathcal{B}} \; \hat{\mathcal{B}} \; \mathscr{B} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Script font sample]

Since it’s now loading all its alphabets from an OpenType math font, math accents work correctly.

Comment: Well, I'd like to use the font of `\mathcal` like the style which the first figure displays. I don't know what font is it , I use `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` can make the character performs what I want, but can't have accent on it.

Comment: @Syvshc I don’t think any OpenType font exactly duplicates the default `\mathcal`. Both Latin Modern and New Computer Modern base theirs on Hermann Zapf’s AMS Euler.