# OpenType math font with similar script letters as computer modern

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I'm trying to replicate a specific script 'X' that I'm seeing in a textbook:

[image: Textbook script X]

This lines up pretty well with the computer modern script X:

[image: Computer Modern script X]

But I'm using the `unicode-math` package, and the script characters in the default font (latin modern) look nothing like the script characters in computer modern (even though it's supposed to just be a modernized version). The `unicode-math` documentation includes a symbol list of a few included fonts, of which the concrete math font gets the closest:

[image: Concrete Math script X]

But I really don't like the uniform stroke thickness - it really doesn't match with the rest of the characters on the page (since I'm otherwise using computer modern / latin modern).

Does anyone know of an OpenType math font that has a similar script X that I'm looking for?

Comment: Are you compelled to load the `unicode-math` package when not using  pdfLaTeX to compile your document? If one doesn't load `unicode-math`, the output of `\mathcal{X}` is the same under both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico Yeah, I'm using other fonts for some other special characters.

Comment: You can always load the CM font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127216/82917

Comment: @campa Sweet, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!