# \mathscr (LaTeX or XeLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, unicode-math

I'm trying to use `\mathscr` in my documents, but it just doesn't show up. I'm using MacTeX, with pdfTeX and XeTeX version 3.1415926 and TeXShop version 3.26. As an MWE, I can use:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex  
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode  
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  
\begin{document}  
$\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$  
\end{document}
```

the first two lines being TeXShop's way to be told to use XeLaTeX (though using pdfTeX changes nothing) and to save the document in UTF-8 Unicode encoding. How do I get the `\mathscr` to appear?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to define a math font, e.g. `XITS Math`

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=setB,StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST}$

\mathversion{setB}%
$\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me. Got error `\setmathfont already defined!`. Seem related to [conflict with mathspec](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/436)

Comment: Works for me but as @karlkoeller says in another answer, lower case letters don't work with \mathscr ... at least for me this example just prints the upper case letters, and only the first set of caps at that.

Answer (score 75):

Talking about pdfLaTeX, the command `\mathscr` from the package `mathrsfs` only support capital letters...

MWE

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode  
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note for users like me who stumble on this hoping it will work for lower-case letters as well: It won't :(

Comment: Is there any other way to get lower-case back?