# Is there a way to get `\mathscr' with lower case letters in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: fonts

The answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151552/ notes that in pdfLaTeX the command`\mathscr` from the package `mathrsfs` only supports capital letters.  Will some other package let me use `\mathscr` in lower case in pdfLaTeX?.

Comment: stix (and stix2) fonts (and packages of same name) have lowercase script alphabet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also can have lowercase script font with `Adobe Bickham` (`bickham` package)  and with  `dutchcal`:

[image]
[image]