# What happen to \mathcal (IEEE conf. sample)

Tags: fonts

I am a beginner in Latex. I used to use \mathcal, for example:

## old code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{C}$
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

I utilize the tex. sample from IEEE (open it with the original software):

http://control.disp.uniroma2.it/cdc2012/author_info.php

I use the same code; however, I got this:

[image]

How do I fix it? (I want the previous one.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please modify your sample document to use the precise setting with the `ieeeconf` class?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. I just use TEX to open it, and type the article.

Comment: I find this article; however, I cannot still fix it.   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120065/xetex-what-happened-to-mathcal-and-mathscr

Comment: If I add `$\mathcal{C}$` in `sample.tex`, I get the first “C”, not the second one.

Comment: When I execute the  sample.tex, there are two errors. After fixing it, I get the same results (the second one). I guess is there any other problem in my software?  I can get the first one in other file instead of the IEEE ones

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be hard-coded in ieeeconf.cls. It loads `mathptmx` by default and as a result, `\mathcal` calls `\mathrsfs`. You can circumvent the problem loading `newtx`, which loads `TeX Gyre Termes`, another Times-clone:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Lalala…
$\mathcal{C}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the package `fourier`, i.e., `\usepackage{fourier}` in your .tex file? For me, when I comment out this package, I get the correct fonts again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).